# Trouble Configuring VNC on AWS Ubuntu amd64 (ami-9eaa1cf6) via Win 8 TightVNC

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, dns, vnc

NOTE: At the bottom of this question I've appended some details I've found that I think are clues as to the underlying problem.

I started out with a clean instance of Ubuntu 14.04 [AMI](http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-9eaa1cf6--ubuntu-images-hvm-ssd-ubuntu-trusty-14-04-amd64-server-20140927) and took the [following steps](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/setting-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-the-amazon-ec2.html) to try to connect via TightVNC Viewer on Windows 8.1:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
3. `sudo apt-get install vnc4server`
4. `vncserver`
5. Entered a VNC password
6. `vncserver -kill :1`
7. `nano .vnc/xstartup`
8. Uncommented the indicated 2 lines for a "normal desktop"
9. added `sh` so the line reads `exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`
10. saved the file
11. rebooted, reconnected PuTTY
12. entered `vncserver`; it said it successfully launched VNC on screen :1
13. Tried to connect to VNC via `127.0.0.1:9000` -- **failed**
14. Tried to connect to VNC via `127.0.0.1::9000`-- **failed**
15. Tried to connect to VNC via  public DNS :5901 -- **failed**
16. Tried to connect to VNC via  public DNS ::5901 -- **failed**
17. Tried to connect to VNC via  public IP  :5901 -- **failed**
18. Tried to connect to VNC via  public IP  ::5901 -- **failed**
19. Tried to connect to VNC via  public DNS with no port specified -- **failed**
20. Tried to connect to VNC via  public IP with no port specified -- **failed**
21. Tried to connect to VNC via  public DNS ::5902 -- **failed**
22. Tried to connect to VNC via  public DNS ::1 -- **failed**
23. Inspected the log, saw that some `xfonts` were missing, installed them
24. Killed `vncserver`
25. rebooted, reconnected via PuTTY, restarted VNC
26. Repeated steps 13-22 with the same results
27. Tried a suggestion I found to try changing `x-manager-window &` to `gnome-session &` in `xstartup`
28. rebooted, still couldn't connect

My `xstartup` file now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
gnome-session &
```

and my log looks like this:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Jan 14 2013 22:28:40
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Sun Nov 30 15:03:35 2014
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
```

I checked `ufw` but the status is inactive, so that's not the problem.

If I use `tightvncserver` instead of `vncserver` then I get the same errors, but the log says:

```
30/11/14 16:55:37 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
30/11/14 16:55:37 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
30/11/14 16:55:37 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
30/11/14 16:55:37 All Rights Reserved.
30/11/14 16:55:37 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
30/11/14 16:55:37 Desktop name 'X' (ip-172-31-57-160:1)
30/11/14 16:55:37 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
30/11/14 16:55:37 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
```

[image]

I've also found that -- despite the fact that `ufw` is off and I have the default security settings for this AWS EC2 instance -- the port is apparently blocked, according to this tool: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ . I have entered an `iptables` command to open it, but still no luck thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work.

In addition to making sure that the AWS Security Groups allow all relevant ports, I made the following changes to PuTTY (my Windows SSH client):

1. Enabled X11 Forwarding under `PuTTY Configuration` --> `Connection` --> `SSH` --> `X11`
2. Set up port forwarding under `PuTTY Configuration` --> `Connection` --> `SSH` --> `Tunnels` for 5901

then I could connect with my VNC Viewer set to `localhost::5901`.